# Gtag load script/custom html

Tags: google-tag-manager, gtag.js

Is it possible with gtag to load custom html / custom script (as in gtm with configuration in gtag admin) or to load a GTM ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with the snippet

```
  (function (w, d, s) {
    var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j = d.createElement(s);
    j.async = true;
    j.src = "{{the url}}";
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
  })(window, document, "script");
```

Just want to make sure you know there is side effect when using this.

The script will be loaded much slower than you just load it in the . This script will need to wait GTM ready.

Comment: Thanks, i have no issue with adding a script with a js code, i would like to know where do i put this in the gtag backoffice ?

Comment: in GTM. Create a custom html and put it on. If it is on your backend. You don't need to do it in gtag. You want to import something which is not GA4 script right?

Comment: I know i can do it in GTM, the question is "Can i add a custom js/htm in GTAG backoffice OR is is possible only through GTM backoffice" ?

Comment: Maybe I'll need you to explain what is Gtag backoffice and GTM backoffice. Not a common word for me when related to GTM or Gtag topic. Or can you add on where exactly you want to put with screenshot?